# Does convexity of all projections imply convexity in higher dimensions?

Tags: convex-analysis, affine-geometry

If I have $n$ 2-dimensional convex "regions" that are the projections along $n$ (independent) dimensions of a n-dimensional compact subspace:

1. Does that imply that the latter is convex? Is the orthogonality of the dimensions needed?
2. What about the reciprocal? (I'm convinced it's true, but if you have a conter-example, shoot :)

Comment: What is a "2-dimensional convex curve"? When you say "domain", do you just mean subset of $\mathbb R^3$, or a connected open subset? What do you mean by reciprocal? In any case, 1) will be false with almost any conditions you put on it. Consider a spherical shell. Its projection in all directions is a disk, but it is not convex.

Comment: A set without holes is called simply connected. However, you could take the open unit ball, and remove the line segment from $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,0,0)$, and it will be an open simply connected subset of $\mathbb R^3$ all of whose projections are convex, but which is not convex.

Comment: @Samuel Sorry for deleting my last comment. Actually, I think you're absolutely right to hit me on details, I should be more precise with my vocabulary... I think the property I was looking for is _compacity_ (it does imply a blob-like structure doesn't it?). The one I originally had in mind was _star domain_ but it's so close to convexity that I felt it would make the question stupid. Thanks for your input anyway :)

Comment: Do you mean compactness? The Menger sponge (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge ) is compact, and I wouldn't say it's very blobby. Not "having holes" is usually formalized as being "simply connected", and not having "indentations", or being "blobby", I would just formalize as "convex". Anyway, even if you require compactness *and* simple-connectedness, there is a counterexample akin to my previous one. I think you should nail down your conditions so your question has a definite answer, and possibly create a new question later when you have more stringent conditions.

Comment: @Samuel Thanks a lot for your patience and explanations :) I guess my real question becomes: What is the "minimal" constraint on a subpart E of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to conclude that it is convex, if we know that its projections along each dimension are convex?

Comment: That's a much harder question, and you should ask that in a new question, but I suspect there are no natural conditions other than assuming $E$ is convex from the beginning. I will answer your question as it is currently stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Consider the closed unit ball, and remove from it all points a distance at most $1/10$ from the open line segment between $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$. This set is compact and simply-connected, but all its projections are convex, despite the set not being convex.
2. If a set is convex, then all its projections are convex. This follows from the definition of convexity. If $x,y$ are two points in the set, then all points on the line segment between $x$ and $y$ are also in the set. When we project the set onto some plane, then the line segment is projected onto a new straight line segment from the projection of $x$ to the projection of $y$. Thus the projection of the set is convex.

Comment: Thanks, that's really clear :)